# Intercept the missile

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, differential-equations, differential-game-theory

A stealth missile $M$ is launched from space station. You, at another space station far away, are trusted with the mission of intercepting $M$ using a single cruise missile $C$ at your disposal .

You know the target missile is traveling in straight line at constant speed $v_m$. You also know the precise location and time at which it was launched. $M$, built by state-of-the-art stealth technology however, is invisible (to you or your $C$). So you have no idea in which direction it is going. Your $C$ has a maximum speed $v_c>v_m$.

Can you control trajectory of $C$ so that it is guaranteed to intercept $M$ in finite time? Is this possible?

---

I can think of 3 apparent possibilities:

1. Precise interception is possible. (It is possible in two dimensions, by calibrating your missile's trajectory to the parameters of certain logarithm spiral).
2. Precise interception is impossible, but for any $\epsilon\gt 0$, paths can be designed so that $C$ can get as close to $M$ as $\epsilon$ in finite time.
3. There's no hope, and your chance of intercepting or getting close to $M$ diminishes as time goes by.

---

This question is inspired by a similar problem in two dimensions by Louis A. Graham in his book *Ingenious Mathematical Problems and Methods*.

Comment: for the two-dimensional problem, see [Tanvolutes: Generalized involutes](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/000298910x515767)

Comment: What do you mean by a "cruise missile"? Cruise missiles have wings and travel in the atmosphere.

Comment: I'm probably missing something here, but I have to ask. It is stated that the stealth missile $M$ is traveling in a straight line, and we know its location and time at launch. If, for instance, both space stations are maintaining same orbit (i.e. their distance is constant); shouldn't that mean that we know the (shortest or longest) path the stealth missile will take assuming the sphere is symmetrical around its x-axis?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no hope. Timothy Budd already explained why staying on the sphere $S_t$ of possible locations of $M$ will not work; so this is to explain why leaving it will not help. What is enough to show is the following **claim**: at large times, if $t_1<t_2$ and $C_{t_{1,2}}$ are at $\epsilon$-neighborhoods of $S_{t_{1,2}}$ respectively, then the radial projections of $C_{t_{1,2}}$ onto the unit sphere are at distance at most $c\cdot \log {t_2/t_1}$ from each other. With the **claim**, essentially the same argument will work.

(Details: think about the task in terms of gradually ruling out possible directions in which $M$ can go. One can only exclude a direction if at some time $t$, $C$ is at the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of the corresponding point of $S_t$. Suppose Alice has a radar that she can direct to any point of $S_t$ and rule out the $2\epsilon$-neighborhood of it. Let Bob follow any strategy, and let Alice do this: whenever Bob's $C$ is in the closed $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $S_t$, she directs the radar to the projection of Bob's $C$ on $S_t$; in between those times, she turns her radar at constant speed. Clearly Alice will know more than Bob, yet by the **claim**, the angular speed of the radar will be bounded by $c/t$, and by Budd's argument, Alice will not be able to rule out everything.)

But the **claim** is fairly obvious: between $t_1$ and $t_2$, $C_t$ cannot get more  than $(v_c-v_m)(t_2-t_1)+2\epsilon$ behind $S_t$, otherwise it wouldn't be able to catch up. If $t_2-t_1<t_1\cdot \frac{v_c-v_m}{100v_m}$, then this means that $C_t$ is always at distance at least $\frac12v_m t$ from the origin, and then the speed of the projection is bounded by $\mathrm{const}/t$ as in Budd's answer. If $t_2/t_1\geq 1+\frac{v_c-v_m}{100v_m}$, then we can just bound the distance between projections of $C_{t_{1,2}}$ by $2$, and take the constant $c$ to be $2\cdot \log\left(1+\frac{v_c-v_m}{100v_m}\right)$

Comment: Well, Timothy has answered that comprehensively: to cover a curve by a curve, you don't need an $\epsilon$-neighborhood at all, just that the length at your disposal is large enough. It's imposible to cover a 2d surface by a curve, you need a neighborhood. In our case, the size of the neighborhood at our disposal decreases too quickly.

Comment: Yes, now I see why. Budd answered my comment just as I posted another one here so I deleted it. Together your answers are really conclusive.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, in this argument, why do we have to make the $S_t$ sphere our anchor and reference points in the first place? What about countless other plans that refers not to $S_t$ at all? "What is enough to show is the following claim..." Why is this claim enough?

Comment: @Eric, I added some explanation, hope that helps!

Answer (score 8):

If $C$ stays on the growing sphere of possible locations of $M$ then there seems to be no hope. Suppose $v_m = 1$ and $v_c = \sqrt{2}$, $t$ is the time since launch and we are trying to get to within distance $\epsilon$ from $M$.

As soon as $C$ reaches the $t$-multiple of the unit sphere, say at time $t=t_0$, it will follow a trajectory $t\cdot x(t)$ with $\|x(t)\|=1$ on the unit sphere with velocity $\|\dot{x}(t)\|=1/t$ (by Pythagoras). The area of the positions of $M$ that $C$ can exclude by moving on the sphere is roughly
$$ \int_{t_0}^t \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t} \frac{\epsilon}{t} = \frac{\epsilon}{t_0} - \frac{\epsilon}{t} < \frac{\epsilon}{t_0}$$
So to exclude an area of order $4\pi$ we are in trouble if $\epsilon < 4\pi t_0$.

Comment: Yes, that strategy is the natural one that comes to mind and was suggested by Robin in the comments. It would work if $v_c(t)=ct+k$, i.e., increasing linearly with time, for possibility 2.

Comment: Oops, somehow I missed that comment.... let me leave the answer as a (trivial) baseline.

Comment: I thought I understood your argument. But now I'm a little confused. What is $x(t)$? Can you explain a bit more in detail about "it will follow a trajectory $t\cdot x(t)$ ... (by Pythagoras)"?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}_+\to S^2\subset\mathbb{R}^3: t\to x(t)$ is the position of C projected onto the unit sphere. The speed of C in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is then $v_c^2=\|x(t)\|^2+t^2\|\dot{x}(t)\|^2=2$ if $\|\dot{x}(t)\|=1/t$.

Comment: But then can't the same function and integration be used to show that it's the same for a unit **circle** in the two dimensional case? Where's the difference?

Comment: There is no $\epsilon/t$ in the integral in the two-dimensional case. The excluded length on the unit circle is then $\int_{t_0}^t \mathrm{d}t/t = \log(t/t_0)$.